# Iterating multi-level json via powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Not able to iterate multilevel Json via PowerShell

`sample.Json`:

```
{
  "GROUP1": [
      
        {
          "name": "a",
          "age": "21"
        },
        {
          "name": "b",
          "age": "22"
        }
        
       ],

  "GROUP2": [
      

          {
            "name": "c",
            "age": "23"
          },
          {
            "name": "d",
            "age": "24"
          }
       ]
}
```

---

```
$set = $args[0]

data = Get-Content -Path "sample.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($i in $data.$set) {

         Write-Host "Name: $i.$set.name age: $i.$set.age"

        }
```

---

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
PS ~> sample.ps1 GROUP1

Name: a age: 21
Name: b age: 22

PS ~> sample.ps1 GROUP2

Name: c age: 23
Name: d age: 24
```

Comment: You're missing the question. What are you expecting as a result of your code?

Comment: EXPECTED OUTPUT

sample.ps1 GROUP1

OUTPUT: Name: a age: 21 Name: b age: 22

sample.ps1 GROUP1

OUTPUT: Name: c age: 23 Name: d age: 24

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the [subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) to allow interpolating the value of `.name` and `.age` in the string but also `$i.$set.name` and `$i.$set.age` are incorrect, `$i` is already an object with properties `.name` and `.age` so, this should work properly:

```
$set = $args[0]
$data = Get-Content -Path 'sample.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($i in $data.$set) {
    Write-Host "Name: $($i.name) Age: $($i.age)"
}
```